# CheckBox to control other check boxes INTERMITTENTLY causing Excel to crash

Tags: excel, forms, vba, checkbox

Greatly appreciated. I can literally halve the code on the text boxes. I don't know if I am over that limit but If you have a moment to glance over it here is the full code.

80% of it is the True/False statements in the old syntax, but could it be because it is such a large sub?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim irow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Master Data")

' Confirmation of Entry to Form

If MsgBox("Have you double checked your data is correct and ALL test points have been selected before entering on the spreadsheet?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then    Exit Sub

' Find first empty cell in Column A after existing data

NextFree = Range("A10:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("A" & NextFree).Select

' Insert row below active cell
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

' Copy Live formula and Out Today formulas down from cells above in Col A, B and C
' Enters the data from the corresponding VBA form into offset cells from active cell reference

Dim lstRw As Long
Dim Rng As Range
lstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("A" & lstRw + 1)
Range("A" & lstRw & ":NK" & lstRw).Copy Range("A" & lstRw + 1)
With Rng
.Offset(, 3) = DateTextBox.Value
.Offset(, 4) = GroupComboBox.Value
.Offset(, 5) = ProjectTextBox.Value
.Offset(, 6) = ReqTextBox.Value
.Offset(, 7) = PartTextBox.Value

.Offset(, 9) = COSHHTextBox.Value
.Offset(, 10) = ContainerComboBox.Value
.Offset(, 11) = SampleIDTextBox.Value


.Offset(, 14) = TechComboBox.Text
.Offset(, 15) = ChemComboBox.Text

    ' Locations For temperatures

.Offset(, 17) = TextBox60Tray.Text
.Offset(, 19) = TextBox50Tray.Text
.Offset(, 21) = TextBox40Tray.Text
.Offset(, 23) = RTTb.Text
.Offset(, 25) = Minus15Tb.Text

    'Brookfield CheckBox Logic statement

    If BrookfieldCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 27).Value = 1
    If BrookfieldCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 27).Value = ""

.Offset(, 28) = BrookfieldKitTextBox.Value

    'AntonParr CheckBox Logic statement

    If AntonParrCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 29).Value = 1
    If AntonParrCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 29).Value = ""

'Filter Index OptionButtons Logic statement

    If Option1.Value = True Then .Offset(, 30).Value = 1
    If Option2.Value = True Then .Offset(, 31).Value = 1

.Offset(, 32) = FilterIndexKitTextBox.Value

    'Malvern Dv90 CheckBox Logic statement

    If MalvernDv90CB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 33).Value = 1
    If MalvernDv90CB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 33).Value = ""

    'Malvern Dn90 CheckBox Logic statement

    If MalvernDv90CB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 34).Value = 1
    If MalvernDv90CB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 34).Value = ""

    'Solvent Malvern CheckBox Logic statement

    If SolvMalvCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 35).Value = 1
    If SolvMalvCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 35).Value = ""

    'Microscope CheckBox Logic statement

    If MicroscopeCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 36).Value = 1
    If MicroscopeCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 36).Value = ""

    'Accusizer CheckBox Logic statement

    If AccusizerCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 37).Value = 1
    If AccusizerCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 37).Value = ""

    'Lumisizer CheckBox Logic statement

    If LumisizerCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 38).Value = 1
    If LumisizerCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 38).Value = ""

    'Surface Tension CheckBox Logic statement

    If SurfaceTCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 39).Value = 1
    If SurfaceTCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 39).Value = ""

    'Phase Angle CheckBox Logic statement

    If PhaseACB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 40).Value = 1
    If PhaseACB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 40).Value = ""

    'Water Content CheckBox Logic statement

    If WaterContCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 41).Value = 1
    If WaterContCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 41).Value = ""

    'pH Testing CheckBox Logic statement

    If pHCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 42).Value = 1
    If pHCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 42).Value = ""

    'Film Properties CheckBox Logic statement

    If FilmPropsCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 43).Value = 1
    If FilmPropsCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 43).Value = ""

    'Karl Fischer CheckBox Logic statement

    If KarlFischerCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 44).Value = 1
    If KarlFischerCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 44).Value = ""

    'Panelling CheckBox Logic statement

    If PanellingCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 45).Value = 1
    If PanellingCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 45).Value = ""

    'Sedimentation CheckBox Logic statement

    If SedimentationCB.Value = True Then .Offset(, 46).Value = 1
    If SedimentationCB.Value = False Then .Offset(, 46).Value = ""

  '60° CheckBox logic statements

    If W1T60.Value = True Then .Offset(, 48).Value = 1
    If W1T60.Value = False Then .Offset(, 48).Value = ""

    If W2T60.Value = True Then .Offset(, 50).Value = 1
    If W2T60.Value = False Then .Offset(, 50).Value = ""

    If W3T60.Value = True Then .Offset(, 52).Value = 1
    If W3T60.Value = False Then .Offset(, 52).Value = ""

    If W4T60.Value = True Then .Offset(, 54).Value = 1
    If W4T60.Value = False Then .Offset(, 54).Value = ""

    If W5T60.Value = True Then .Offset(, 56).Value = 1
    If W5T60.Value = False Then .Offset(, 56).Value = ""

    If W6T60.Value = True Then .Offset(, 58).Value = 1
    If W6T60.Value = False Then .Offset(, 58).Value = ""

    If W7T60.Value = True Then .Offset(, 60).Value = 1
    If W7T60.Value = False Then .Offset(, 60).Value = ""

    If W8T60.Value = True Then .Offset(, 62).Value = 1
    If W8T60.Value = False Then .Offset(, 62).Value = ""

  '50° CheckBox logic statements

    If Wk1T50.Value = True Then .Offset(, 64).Value = 1
    If Wk1T50.Value = False Then .Offset(, 64).Value = ""

    If Wk2T50.Value = True Then .Offset(, 66).Value = 1
    If Wk2T50.Value = False Then .Offset(, 66).Value = ""

    If WK3T50.Value = True Then .Offset(, 68).Value = 1
    If WK3T50.Value = False Then .Offset(, 68).Value = ""

    If WK4T50.Value = True Then .Offset(, 70).Value = 1
    If WK4T50.Value = False Then .Offset(, 70).Value = ""

    If WEEK5T50.Value = True Then .Offset(, 72).Value = 1
    If WEEK5T50.Value = False Then .Offset(, 72).Value = ""

    If WK6T50.Value = True Then .Offset(, 74).Value = 1
    If WK6T50.Value = False Then .Offset(, 74).Value = ""

    If WK7T50.Value = True Then .Offset(, 76).Value = 1
    If WK7T50.Value = False Then .Offset(, 76).Value = ""

    If WK8T50.Value = True Then .Offset(, 78).Value = 1
    If WK8T50.Value = False Then .Offset(, 78).Value = ""

    If WK10T50.Value = True Then .Offset(, 80).Value = 1
    If WK10T50.Value = False Then .Offset(, 80).Value = ""

    If WK12T50.Value = True Then .Offset(, 82).Value = 1
    If WK12T50.Value = False Then .Offset(, 82).Value = ""

    If WK14T50.Value = True Then .Offset(, 84).Value = 1
    If WK14T50.Value = False Then .Offset(, 84).Value = ""

    If WK16T50.Value = True Then .Offset(, 86).Value = 1
    If WK16T50.Value = False Then .Offset(, 86).Value = ""

 '40° CheckBox logic statements

    If WK1T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 88).Value = 1
    If WK1T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 88).Value = ""

    If WK2T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 90).Value = 1
    If WK2T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 90).Value = ""

    If WK3T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 92).Value = 1
    If WK3T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 92).Value = ""

    If WK4T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 94).Value = 1
    If WK4T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 94).Value = ""

    If WK5T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 96).Value = 1
    If WK5T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 96).Value = ""

    If WK6T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 98).Value = 1
    If WK6T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 98).Value = ""

    If WK7T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 100).Value = 1
    If WK7T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 100).Value = ""

    If WK8T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 102).Value = 1
    If WK8T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 102).Value = ""

    If WK10T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 104).Value = 1
    If WK10T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 104).Value = ""

    If WK12T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 106).Value = 1
    If WK12T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 106).Value = ""

    If WK14T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 108).Value = 1
    If WK14T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 108).Value = ""

    If WK16T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 110).Value = 1
    If WK16T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 110).Value = ""

    If WK20T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 112).Value = 1
    If WK20T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 112).Value = ""

    If WK24T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 114).Value = 1
    If WK24T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 114).Value = ""

    If WK28T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 116).Value = 1
    If WK28T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 116).Value = ""

    If WK32T40.Value = True Then .Offset(, 118).Value = 1
    If WK32T40.Value = False Then .Offset(, 118).Value = ""


   '1 - 104wk CheckBox logic statements

    If wk1tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 120).Value = 1
    If wk1tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 120).Value = ""

    If wk2tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 122).Value = 1
    If wk2tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 122).Value = ""

    If wk3tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 124).Value = 1
    If wk3tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 124).Value = ""

    If wk4tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 126).Value = 1
    If wk4tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 126).Value = ""

    If wk5tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 128).Value = 1
    If wk5tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 128).Value = ""

    If wk6tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 130).Value = 1
    If wk6tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 130).Value = ""

    If wk7tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 132).Value = 1
    If wk7tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 132).Value = ""

    If wk8tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 134).Value = 1
    If wk8tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 134).Value = ""

    If wk9tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 136).Value = 1
    If wk9tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 136).Value = ""

    If wk10tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 138).Value = 1
    If wk10tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 138).Value = ""

    If wk11tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 140).Value = 1
    If wk11tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 140).Value = ""

    If wk12tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 142).Value = 1
    If wk12tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 142).Value = ""

    If wk13tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 144).Value = 1
    If wk13tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 144).Value = ""

    If wk14tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 146).Value = 1
    If wk14tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 146).Value = ""

    If wk15tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 148).Value = 1
    If wk15tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 148).Value = ""

    If wk16tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 150).Value = 1
    If wk16tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 150).Value = ""

    If wk17tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 152).Value = 1
    If wk17tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 152).Value = ""

    If wk18tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 154).Value = 1
    If wk18tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 154).Value = ""

    If wk19tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 156).Value = 1
    If wk19tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 156).Value = ""

    If wk20tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 158).Value = 1
    If wk20tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 158).Value = ""

    If wk21tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 160).Value = 1
    If wk21tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 160).Value = ""

    If wk22tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 162).Value = 1
    If wk22tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 162).Value = ""

    If wk23tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 164).Value = 1
    If wk23tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 164).Value = ""

    If wk24tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 166).Value = 1
    If wk24tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 166).Value = ""

    If wk25tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 168).Value = 1
    If wk25tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 168).Value = ""

    If wk26tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 170).Value = 1
    If wk26tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 170).Value = ""

    If wk27tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 172).Value = 1
    If wk27tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 172).Value = ""

    If wk28tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 174).Value = 1
    If wk28tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 174).Value = ""

    If wk29tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 176).Value = 1
    If wk29tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 176).Value = ""

    If wk30tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 178).Value = 1
    If wk30tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 178).Value = ""

    If wk31tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 180).Value = 1
    If wk31tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 180).Value = ""

    If wk32tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 182).Value = 1
    If wk32tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 182).Value = ""

    If wk33tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 184).Value = 1
    If wk33tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 184).Value = ""

    If wk34tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 186).Value = 1
    If wk34tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 186).Value = ""

    If wk35tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 188).Value = 1
    If wk35tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 188).Value = ""

    If wk36tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 190).Value = 1
    If wk36tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 190).Value = ""

    If wk37tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 192).Value = 1
    If wk37tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 192).Value = ""

    If wk38tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 194).Value = 1
    If wk38tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 194).Value = ""

    If wk39tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 196).Value = 1
    If wk39tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 196).Value = ""

    If wk40tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 198).Value = 1
    If wk40tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 198).Value = ""

    If wk41tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 200).Value = 1
    If wk41tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 200).Value = ""

    If wk42tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 202).Value = 1
    If wk42tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 202).Value = ""

    If wk43tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 204).Value = 1
    If wk43tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 204).Value = ""

    If wk44tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 206).Value = 1
    If wk44tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 206).Value = ""

    If wk45tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 208).Value = 1
    If wk45tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 208).Value = ""

    If wk46tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 210).Value = 1
    If wk46tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 210).Value = ""

    If wk47tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 212).Value = 1
    If wk47tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 212).Value = ""

    If wk48tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 214).Value = 1
    If wk48tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 214).Value = ""

    If wk49tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 216).Value = 1
    If wk49tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 216).Value = ""

    If wk50tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 218).Value = 1
    If wk50tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 218).Value = ""

    If wk51tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 220).Value = 1
    If wk51tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 220).Value = ""

    If wk52tb.Value = True Then .Offset(, 222).Value = 1
    If wk52tb.Value = False Then .Offset(, 222).Value = ""


    '-15° CheckBox logic statements

    If WK1T15.Value = True Then .Offset(, 328).Value = 1
    If WK1T15.Value = False Then .Offset(, 328).Value = ""

    If WK2T15.Value = True Then .Offset(, 330).Value = 1
    If WK2T15.Value = False Then .Offset(, 330).Value = ""

    If WK3T15.Value = True Then .Offset(, 332).Value = 1
    If WK3T15.Value = False Then .Offset(, 332).Value = ""

    If WK4T15.Value = True Then .Offset(, 334).Value = 1
    If WK4T15.Value = False Then .Offset(, 334).Value = ""

    If WK5T15.Value = True Then .Offset(, 336).Value = 1
    If WK5T15.Value = False Then .Offset(, 336).Value = ""

    If WK6T15.Value = True Then .Offset(, 338).Value = 1
    If WK6T15.Value = False Then .Offset(, 338).Value = ""

    If WK7T15.Value = True Then .Offset(, 340).Value = 1
    If WK7T15.Value = False Then .Offset(, 340).Value = ""

    If WK8T15.Value = True Then .Offset(, 342).Value = 1
    If WK8T15.Value = False Then .Offset(, 342).Value = ""

 '-15° CheckBox logic statements

    If WK1TFRIDGE.Value = True Then .Offset(, 344).Value = 1
    If WK1TFRIDGE.Value = False Then .Offset(, 344).Value = ""

    If WK2TFRIDGE.Value = True Then .Offset(, 346).Value = 1
    If WK2TFRIDGE.Value = False Then .Offset(, 346).Value = ""

    If WK3TFRIDGE.Value = True Then .Offset(, 348).Value = 1
    If WK3TFRIDGE.Value = False Then .Offset(, 348).Value = ""

    If WK4TFRIDGE.Value = True Then .Offset(, 350).Value = 1
    If WK4TFRIDGE.Value = False Then .Offset(, 350).Value = ""

    If WK5TFRIDGE.Value = True Then .Offset(, 352).Value = 1
    If WK5TFRIDGE.Value = False Then .Offset(, 352).Value = ""

    If WK6TFRIDGE.Value = True Then .Offset(, 354).Value = 1
    If WK6TFRIDGE.Value = False Then .Offset(, 354).Value = ""

    If WK7TFRIDGE.Value = True Then .Offset(, 356).Value = 1
    If WK7TFRIDGE.Value = False Then .Offset(, 356).Value = ""

    If WK8TFRIDGE.Value = True Then .Offset(, 358).Value = 1
    If WK8TFRIDGE.Value = False Then .Offset(, 358).Value = ""


End With


End Sub


Private Sub Gate60Tb_Click()

'60° Gate TickBox Control

Me.W1T60.Value = Me.Gate60Tb.Value

Me.W2T60.Value = Me.Gate60Tb.Value

Me.W3T60.Value = Me.Gate60Tb.Value

Me.W4T60.Value = Me.Gate60Tb.Value

End Sub
Private Sub Gate50Tb_Click()

    '50° Gate TickBox Control

    If Gate50Tb.Value = True Then Wk2T50.Value = 1
    If Gate50Tb.Value = False Then Wk2T50.Value = 0

    If Gate50Tb.Value = True Then WK4T50.Value = 1
    If Gate50Tb.Value = False Then WK4T50.Value = 0

    If Gate50Tb.Value = True Then WK6T50.Value = 1
    If Gate50Tb.Value = False Then WK6T50.Value = 0

    If Gate50Tb.Value = True Then WK8T50.Value = 1
    If Gate50Tb.Value = False Then WK8T50.Value = 0


End Sub

Private Sub Gate40Tb_Click()

    ' Gate 40° Tickbox Control

    If Gate40Tb.Value = True Then WK4T40.Value = 1
    If Gate40Tb.Value = False Then WK4T40.Value = 0

    If Gate40Tb.Value = True Then WK8T40.Value = 1
    If Gate40Tb.Value = False Then WK8T40.Value = 0

    If Gate40Tb.Value = True Then WK12T40.Value = 1
    If Gate40Tb.Value = False Then WK12T40.Value = 0

    If Gate40Tb.Value = True Then WK16T40.Value = 1
    If Gate40Tb.Value = False Then WK16T40.Value = 0

End Sub

Private Sub GateRT48wk_Click()


    If GateRT48wk.Value = True Then wk6tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT48wk.Value = False Then wk6tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT48wk.Value = True Then wk12tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT48wk.Value = False Then wk12tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT48wk.Value = True Then wk18tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT48wk.Value = False Then wk18tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT48wk.Value = True Then wk24tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT48wk.Value = False Then wk24tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT48wk.Value = True Then wk30tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT48wk.Value = False Then wk30tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT48wk.Value = True Then wk36tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT48wk.Value = False Then wk36tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT48wk.Value = True Then wk42tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT48wk.Value = False Then wk42tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT48wk.Value = True Then wk48tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT48wk.Value = False Then wk48tb.Value = 0

End Sub

Private Sub GateRT52wk_Click()

    ' Gate RT Tickbox Control

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk4tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk4tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk8tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk8tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk12tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk12tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk16tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk16tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk20tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk20tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk24tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk24tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk28tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk28tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk32tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk32tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk36tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk36tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk40tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk40tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk44tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk44tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk48tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk48tb.Value = 0

    If GateRT52wk.Value = True Then wk52tb.Value = 1
    If GateRT52wk.Value = False Then wk52tb.Value = 0

End Sub


Private Sub GateRTQ1_Click()

    ' Gate RT Year 1 Qtly Tickbox Control

    If GateRTQ1.Value = True Then wk13tb.Value = 1
    If GateRTQ1.Value = False Then wk13tb.Value = 0

    If GateRTQ1.Value = True Then wk26tb.Value = 1
    If GateRTQ1.Value = False Then wk26tb.Value = 0

    If GateRTQ1.Value = True Then wk39tb.Value = 1
    If GateRTQ1.Value = False Then wk39tb.Value = 0

    If GateRTQ1.Value = True Then wk52tb.Value = 1
    If GateRTQ1.Value = False Then wk52tb.Value = 0

End Sub

Private Sub GateRTQ2_Click()

    ' Gate RT Year 2 Qtly Tickbox Control

    If GateRTQ2.Value = True Then wk65tb.Value = 1
    If GateRTQ2.Value = False Then wk65tb.Value = 0

    If GateRTQ2.Value = True Then wk78tb.Value = 1
    If GateRTQ2.Value = False Then wk78tb.Value = 0

    If GateRTQ2.Value = True Then wk91tb.Value = 1
    If GateRTQ2.Value = False Then wk91tb.Value = 0

    If GateRTQ2.Value = True Then wk104tb.Value = 1
    If GateRTQ2.Value = False Then wk104tb.Value = 0

End Sub


Private Sub Gate158wk_Click()

    '-15° 8@8 Gate TickBox Control

    If Gate158wk.Value = True Then WK8T15.Value = 1
    If Gate158wk.Value = False Then WK8T15.Value = 0

End Sub

Private Sub Gate151wk_Click()

    '-15° 8@1 Gate TickBox Control

    If Gate151wk.Value = True Then WK1T15.Value = 1
    If Gate151wk.Value = False Then WK1T15.Value = 0

    If Gate151wk.Value = True Then WK2T15.Value = 1
    If Gate151wk.Value = False Then WK2T15.Value = 0

    If Gate151wk.Value = True Then WK3T15.Value = 1
    If Gate151wk.Value = False Then WK3T15.Value = 0

    If Gate151wk.Value = True Then WK4T15.Value = 1
    If Gate151wk.Value = False Then WK4T15.Value = 0

    If Gate151wk.Value = True Then WK5T15.Value = 1
    If Gate151wk.Value = False Then WK5T15.Value = 0

    If Gate151wk.Value = True Then WK6T15.Value = 1
    If Gate151wk.Value = False Then WK6T15.Value = 0

    If Gate151wk.Value = True Then WK7T15.Value = 1
    If Gate151wk.Value = False Then WK7T15.Value = 0

    If Gate151wk.Value = True Then WK8T15.Value = 1
    If Gate151wk.Value = False Then WK8T15.Value = 0


End Sub
Private Sub GateFridge8wk_Click()

    'Fridge 8@8 Gate TickBox Control

    If GateFridge8wk.Value = True Then WK8TFRIDGE.Value = 1
    If GateFridge8wk.Value = False Then WK8TFRIDGE.Value = 0

End Sub

Private Sub GateFridge1wk_Click()

    '-15° 8@1 Gate TickBox Control

    If GateFridge1wk.Value = True Then WK1TFRIDGE.Value = 1
    If GateFridge1wk.Value = False Then WK1TFRIDGE.Value = 0

    If GateFridge1wk.Value = True Then WK2TFRIDGE.Value = 1
    If GateFridge1wk.Value = False Then WK2TFRIDGE.Value = 0

    If GateFridge1wk.Value = True Then WK3TFRIDGE.Value = 1
    If GateFridge1wk.Value = False Then WK3TFRIDGE.Value = 0

    If GateFridge1wk.Value = True Then WK4TFRIDGE.Value = 1
    If GateFridge1wk.Value = False Then WK4TFRIDGE.Value = 0

    If GateFridge1wk.Value = True Then WK5TFRIDGE.Value = 1
    If GateFridge1wk.Value = False Then WK5TFRIDGE.Value = 0

    If GateFridge1wk.Value = True Then WK6TFRIDGE.Value = 1
    If GateFridge1wk.Value = False Then WK6TFRIDGE.Value = 0

    If GateFridge1wk.Value = True Then WK7TFRIDGE.Value = 1
    If GateFridge1wk.Value = False Then WK7TFRIDGE.Value = 0

    If GateFridge1wk.Value = True Then WK8TFRIDGE.Value = 1
    If GateFridge1wk.Value = False Then WK8TFRIDGE.Value = 0


End Sub
```

Comment: Did you have multiple crashes with the above code? As you stated at one point it works perfect and at the same time it crashes. Its either option A or B.

Comment: Set the checkbox value = True (aka -1) OR False (aka 0)

Comment: Do any of the checkboxes which are being set from (eg) `Gate60Tb_Click`  also have their own event handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found people elsewhere that have experience of forms with many controls and they say that once you get above about 200 controls, you may start noticing some strange/intermittent occurrences/errors.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689794/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-controls-that-a-vba-form-can-hold)

I would reduce the number of controls on your form.

Also you might simplify the code:

```
Private Sub Gate60Tb_Click()

    '60° Gate TickBox Control

    Me.W1T60.Value = Me.Gate60Tb.Value

    Me.W2T60.Value = Me.Gate60Tb.Value

    Me.W3T60.Value = Me.Gate60Tb.Value

    Me.W4T60.Value = Me.Gate60Tb.Value

End Sub
```

Note that addin "Me" fully qualifies the control.  I wonder if you are inadvertantly picking up another in scope object with the name that has teh same name as a control that you THINK is on your form.

Other possibles:

```
Private Sub Gate60Tb_Click()

    '60° Gate TickBox Control

    with Me.Gate60Tb

    Me.W1T60.Value = .Value

    Me.W2T60.Value = .Value

    Me.W3T60.Value = .Value

    Me.W4T60.Value = .Value

    end with

End Sub


Private Sub Gate60Tb_Click()

    '60° Gate TickBox Control

    Dim bln as boolean 

    bln =  Me.Gate60Tb

    Me.W1T60.Value = bln 

    Me.W2T60.Value = bln 

    Me.W3T60.Value = bln 

    Me.W4T60.Value = bln 


End Sub
```

Comment: This is a far more elegant execution definitely and will reduce my code by a couple hundred lines however I am still getting the same crash..

I am fairly new to coding and I suspect maybe it is how my full code is laid out potentially.

Comment: I ha da play.  I tried setting locked and enable properties.  I tried using other event handlers as well.  I could not get any issues to happen.
I can't help more.  All I woudl suggest is to half the nubmer of contorls (to simplyfy the probelm) and see if the error still happens.  That will at least help you narrow it down. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689794/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-controls-that-a-vba-form-can-hold.  Which says that once you get above about 200 controls, you may start noticing some strange/intermittent occurrences/errors.

Comment: Hi, if you would take one moment I have put the full code in an edit on the post. Could it be that how it is all laid out in the code under the form? do i need to split it into smaller parts?

Comment: i deleted half the controls as proof of concept and it seems that there is no crash occurring, so it's not ideal and i will have to review my code nonetheless but at least i know the root cause, regards!