# Automation Error VBA from Userform

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, userform

Keep getting an automation error when my userform uses the below code when it initializes. I dont get an error when i take it out. The userform is being called from a shape using a module. the text from the userform is stored under a sheet called "Compliance". My userform is also called compliance. Here is my code below, any help would be much appreciated:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("compliance")
On Error Resume Next
With page1

  employee1.Value = ws.Range("B2")
  employee2.Value = ws.Range("B3")
  employee3.Value = ws.Range("B4")
  employee4.Value = ws.Range("B5")
  employee5.Value = ws.Range("B5")
  employee6.Value = ws.Range("B6")

  '//// setting ops grade

 grade1.Value = ws.Range("D2")
 grade2.Value = ws.Range("D3")
 grade3.Value = ws.Range("D4")
 grade4.Value = ws.Range("D5")
 grade5.Value = ws.Range("D6")
grade6.Value = ws.Range("D7")

  '//// setting employee compliance recap

 recap1.Value = ws.Range("F2")
 recap2.Value = ws.Range("F3")
 recap3.Value = ws.Range("F4")
 recap4.Value = ws.Range("F5")
 recap5.Value = ws.Range("F6")
 recap6.Value = ws.Range("F7")




  '////////////////////////////////////////// febraury
'//// setting employees interviewed
With page2

 febemp1.Value = ws.Range("B14")
 febemp2.Value = ws.Range("B15")
 febemp3.Value = ws.Range("B16")
 febemp4.Value = ws.Range("B17")
 febemp5.Value = ws.Range("B18")
 febemp6.Value = ws.Range("B19")


febgrd1.Value = ws.Range("D14")
febgrd2.Value = ws.Range("D15")
febgrd3.Value = ws.Range("D16")
febgrd4.Value = ws.Range("D17")
febgrd5.Value = ws.Range("D18")
febgrd6.Value = ws.Range("D19")


 febrecap1.Value = ws.Range("F14")
 febrecap2.Value = ws.Range("F15")
 febrecap3.Value = ws.Range("F16")
 febrecap4.Value = ws.Range("F17")
 febrecap5.Value = ws.Range("F18")
 febrecap6.Value = ws.Range("F19")



With page3

 marchemp1.Value = ws.Range("B26")
 marchemp2.Value = ws.Range("B27")
 marchemp3.Value = ws.Range("B28")
 marchemp4.Value = ws.Range("B29")
 marchemp5.Value = ws.Range("B30")
 marchemp6.Value = ws.Range("B31")


marchgrd1.Value = ws.Range("D26")
marchgrd2.Value = ws.Range("D27")
marchgrd3.Value = ws.Range("D28")
marchgrd4.Value = ws.Range("D29")
marchgrd5.Value = ws.Range("D30")
marchgrd6.Value = ws.Range("D31")


marchrecap1.Value = ws.Range("F26")
marchrecap2.Value = ws.Range("F27")
marchrecap3.Value = ws.Range("F28")
marchrecap4.Value = ws.Range("F29")
marchrecap5.Value = ws.Range("F30")
marchrecap6.Value = ws.Range("F31")


  With page4

apremp1.Value = ws.Range("B38")
apremp2.Value = ws.Range("B39")
apremp3.Value = ws.Range("B40")
apremp4.Value = ws.Range("B41")
apremp5.Value = ws.Range("B42")
apremp6.Value = ws.Range("B43")


 aprgrd1.Value = ws.Range("D38")
 aprgrd2.Value = ws.Range("D39")
 aprgrd3.Value = ws.Range("D40")
 aprgrd4.Value = ws.Range("D41")
 aprgrd5.Value = ws.Range("D42")
 aprgrd6.Value = ws.Range("D43")


aprrecap1.Value = ws.Range("F38")
aprrecap2.Value = ws.Range("F39")
aprrecap3.Value = ws.Range("F40")
aprrecap4.Value = ws.Range("F41")
aprrecap5.Value = ws.Range("F42")
aprrecap6.Value = ws.Range("F43")

  With page5

mayemp1.Value = ws.Range("B50")
mayemp2.Value = ws.Range("B51")
mayemp3.Value = ws.Range("B52")
mayemp4.Value = ws.Range("B53")
mayemp5.Value = ws.Range("B54")
mayemp6.Value = ws.Range("B55")


 maygrd1.Value = ws.Range("D50")
 maygrd2.Value = ws.Range("D51")
 maygrd3.Value = ws.Range("D52")
 maygrd4.Value = ws.Range("D53")
 maygrd5.Value = ws.Range("D54")
 maygrd6.Value = ws.Range("D55")


mayrecap1.Value = ws.Range("F50")
mayrecap2.Value = ws.Range("F51")
mayrecap3.Value = ws.Range("F52")
mayrecap4.Value = ws.Range("F53")
mayrecap5.Value = ws.Range("F54")
mayrecap6.Value = ws.Range("F55")


  With page6

junemp1.Value = ws.Range("B62")
junemp2.Value = ws.Range("B63")
junemp3.Value = ws.Range("B64")
junemp4.Value = ws.Range("B65")
junemp5.Value = ws.Range("B66")
junemp6.Value = ws.Range("B67")


jungrd1.Value = ws.Range("D62")
jungrd2.Value = ws.Range("D63")
jungrd3.Value = ws.Range("D64")
jungrd4.Value = ws.Range("D65")
jungrd5.Value = ws.Range("D66")
jungrd6.Value = ws.Range("D67")


junrecap1.Value = ws.Range("F62")
junrecap2.Value = ws.Range("F63")
junrecap3.Value = ws.Range("F64")
junrecap4.Value = ws.Range("F65")
junrecap5.Value = ws.Range("F66")
junrecap6.Value = ws.Range("F67")

  With page7

julemp1.Value = ws.Range("B74")
julemp2.Value = ws.Range("B75")
julemp3.Value = ws.Range("B76")
julemp4.Value = ws.Range("B77")
julemp5.Value = ws.Range("B78")
julemp6.Value = ws.Range("B79")


julgrd1.Value = ws.Range("D74")
julgrd2.Value = ws.Range("D75")
julgrd3.Value = ws.Range("D76")
julgrd4.Value = ws.Range("D77")
julgrd5.Value = ws.Range("D78")
julgrd6.Value = ws.Range("D79")


julrecap1.Value = ws.Range("F74")
julrecap2.Value = ws.Range("F75")
julrecap3.Value = ws.Range("F76")
julrecap4.Value = ws.Range("F77")
julrecap5.Value = ws.Range("F78")
julrecap6.Value = ws.Range("F79")


  With page8

augemp1.Value = ws.Range("B86")
augemp2.Value = ws.Range("B87")
augemp3.Value = ws.Range("B88")
augemp4.Value = ws.Range("B89")
augemp5.Value = ws.Range("B90")
augemp6.Value = ws.Range("B91")


auggrd1.Value = ws.Range("D86")
auggrd2.Value = ws.Range("D87")
auggrd3.Value = ws.Range("D88")
auggrd4.Value = ws.Range("D89")
auggrd5.Value = ws.Range("D90")
auggrd6.Value = ws.Range("D91")


augrecap1.Value = ws.Range("F86")
augrecap2.Value = ws.Range("F87")
augrecap3.Value = ws.Range("F88")
augrecap4.Value = ws.Range("F89")
augrecap5.Value = ws.Range("F90")
augrecap6.Value = ws.Range("F91")

  With page9

sepemp1.Value = ws.Range("B98")
sepemp2.Value = ws.Range("B99")
sepemp3.Value = ws.Range("B100")
sepemp4.Value = ws.Range("B101")
sepemp5.Value = ws.Range("B102")
sepemp6.Value = ws.Range("B103")

sepgrd1.Value = ws.Range("D98")
sepgrd2.Value = ws.Range("D99")
sepgrd3.Value = ws.Range("D100")
 sepgrd4.Value = ws.Range("D101")
 sepgrd5.Value = ws.Range("D102")
 sepgrd6.Value = ws.Range("D103")



seprecap1.Value = ws.Range("F98")
seprecap2.Value = ws.Range("F99")
seprecap3.Value = ws.Range("F100")
seprecap4.Value = ws.Range("F101")
seprecap5.Value = ws.Range("F102")
seprecap6.Value = ws.Range("F103")

  With page10

  octemp1.Value = ws.Range("B110")
  octemp2.Value = ws.Range("B111")
 octemp3.Value = ws.Range("B112")
  octemp4.Value = ws.Range("B113")
  octemp5.Value = ws.Range("B114")
 octemp6.Value = ws.Range("B115")



  octgrd1.Value = ws.Range("D110")
   octgrd2.Value = ws.Range("D111")
  octgrd3.Value = ws.Range("D112")
  octgrd4.Value = ws.Range("D113")
  octgrd5.Value = ws.Range("D114")
  octgrd6.Value = ws.Range("D115")


  octrecap1.Value = ws.Range("F110")
  octrecap2.Value = ws.Range("F111")
  octrecap3.Value = ws.Range("F112")
  octrecap4.Value = ws.Range("F113")
  octrecap5.Value = ws.Range("F114")
  octrecap6.Value = ws.Range("F115")

  With page11

  novemp1.Value = ws.Range("B122")
  novemp2.Value = ws.Range("B123")
  novemp3.Value = ws.Range("B124")
  novemp4.Value = ws.Range("B125")
  novemp5.Value = ws.Range("B126")
  novemp6.Value = ws.Range("B127")


  novgrd1.Value = ws.Range("D122")
  novgrd2.Value = ws.Range("D123")
  novgrd3.Value = ws.Range("D124")
  novgrd4.Value = ws.Range("D125")
  novgrd5.Value = ws.Range("D126")
  novgrd6.Value = ws.Range("D127")

novrecap1.Value = ws.Range("F122")
novrecap2.Value = ws.Range("F123")
novrecap3.Value = ws.Range("F124")
novrecap4.Value = ws.Range("F125")
novrecap5.Value = ws.Range("F126")
novrecap6.Value = ws.Range("F127")


  With page12

decemp1.Value = ws.Range("B134")
decemp2.Value = ws.Range("B135")
decemp3.Value = ws.Range("B136")
decemp4.Value = ws.Range("B137")
decemp5.Value = ws.Range("B138")
decemp6.Value = ws.Range("B139")


 decgrd1.Value = ws.Range("D134")
 decgrd2.Value = ws.Range("D135")
 decgrd3.Value = ws.Range("D136")
 decgrd4.Value = ws.Range("D137")
 decgrd5.Value = ws.Range("D138")
 decgrd6.Value = ws.Range("D139")


decrecap1.Value = ws.Range("F134")
decrecap2.Value = ws.Range("F135")
decrecap3.Value = ws.Range("F136")
decrecap4.Value = ws.Range("F137")
decrecap5.Value = ws.Range("F138")
decrecap6.Value = ws.Range("F139")


End With
    End With
        End With
            End With
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
End With
End With
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: **A)** End your `End With` blocks when you are done with it. Not all at once at the end. **B)** limit your code you share here to relevant code. **C)** Remove 'On Error Resume Next' and re-run

Comment: For your first `With Block` you need to use `End With` before `With page2`

Comment: Remove the `On Error Resume Next`. Do you get an error on a specific line? Also, `Sheets` is implicitly referencing the `ActiveWorkbook` is the correct workbook active?  What is `page1` and where is that set?

Comment: @Comintern i am not getting an error on a specific line, just a pop up dialog when my userform tries to open from a Sub that is linked to a shape. Page1 - Page 12 are multipages on my userform

Comment: None of your With blocks do anything - nothing is scoped to them with a leading period.

Comment: This code could be a fraction of the size (and easier to debug/maintain) with a few loops and use of `Me.Controls(controlNameHere)`

Comment: @TimWilliams i took out `With Page1 - Page12` and still getting automation error

Answer (score 1):

Untested - too many controls to make...

You'd need to harmonize your control naming a bit, but something like this should work:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, mNum As Long, months, i As Long, m
    Dim c As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("compliance")
    Set c = ws.Range("B1")

    months = Array("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", _
                   "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec")

    For mNum = 1 To 12
        m = months(m - 1)
        With Me.MultiPage1.Pages("page" & mNum)
            For i = 1 To 6
                .Controls(m & "emp" & i).Value = c.Offset(i, 0).Value
                .Controls(m & "grd" & i).Value = c.Offset(i, 2).Value
                .Controls(m & "recap" & i).Value = c.Offset(i, 4).Value
            Next i
        End With
        Set c = c.Offset(12, 0)
    Next mNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Additional hint: Though there is no fixed limit of controls per se that a userform can hold, there seems to be a a long standing limitation on the number of controls that can be addressed directly by their name  -
 c.f. [Not enough memory - crash when loading VBA userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140753/not-enough-memory-crash-when-loading-vba-userform?noredirect=1#comment87341599_50140753).
 Therefore I'd recommend not only to minimize the absolute number of value controls, but to address such big control sets preferrably via the (Multipage.Pages') `Controls` collection.

Comment: You don't really even need 12 pages - each month could be loaded "on demand" and displayed in a single page.

Comment: I can only agree with Tim's words in comment (BTW a fine answer) - so you could consider the use of a *register control* and only **one** set of dynamically linked textboxes instead of 12 multipages multiplied by 18 textboxes.