# Userform multipage does not refresh

Tags: excel, vba, multipage

I'm working on a VBA application that consists of few pages on multipage.
[image]

I have a list of items on page 0 and when I click on that item, Excel should move to a different page.

The code:

```
Userform1.MultiPage1.Value = 1
```

This does not happen. Page 1 is not shown even though it is selected (tab on top of the multipage is selected).

I have quite a bit of code prior to above shown code and everything seems to be working.

I have read on Google that the problem could be due to declaring the same variable more than once. Code checked and looks ok now.
I also read that the form can be corrupted. I hope it isn't because there is a lot of stuff on it.

Any idea why the multipage doesn't change the page and how to fix it?

On attached picture you can see that the multipage has changed from 'page1' to 'video_exhibit', however it did not update the view. just stayed on the same page.
Multipage was working prior to this stage of the application.

I shared the files on Google drive at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12LTuaMoQ-HpI1z8g9F2419dHvHQU4f_4?usp=sharing
uploaded are: rar, zip and exports from app. userform and modules.
I'm aware there is lots to fix and unnecessary loops, but this can wait as I just need a draft working.

Comment: When are you running that code? It it's in the `Multipage1_Change` event, it will not work.

Comment: Also remember that the first multipage tab is `0`, not `1`.

Comment: I'm running that code on listbox selection change. i deleted the multipage1_change code (it was empty anyway), but the problem is still there. the annoying part it that the app was working fine before so I made an error somewhere in the code. I'm trying to go line by line now and spot the error. Do you think this can be corrupted? I hope not

Comment: Do you have any other code thats setting the multipage ?

Comment: MaMe what do you mean? I do have few pages and i was able to jump between them. but to go through the pages i'm using multipage1.value

Comment: Is it possible, that your code is deselecting the pages because some other events or functions are getting called containing the Userform1.MultiPage1.Value property ?

Your buggy page is displaying properly inside the vba editor ?
On that page, are you using some external usercontrol that is bugging around ?

Comment: It's definitely somewhere in the code, but I can't figure it out yet. Or maybe it's corrupted. I can use the app and all multipage work fine. until I run this code UserForm1.MultiPage1.value = 8

Sheets("Video").Activate
UserForm1.display_exhibit_name.value = Range("B" & current_exhibit).value
UserForm1.display_video_codec.value = Range("c" & current_exhibit).value
UserForm1.display_audio_codec.value = Range("d" & current_exhibit).value
but this code looks fine to me. I'm still digging, but struggling a lot. Thank you for your help

Comment: 0

Hard to say without seeing all of your code.

Commit all lines from above and decommit them step by step to see which line breaks the pageview.

Comment: I have another idea. Is it possible that excel runs out of memory or something. when i click on different tabs on multipage, only after some time it starts responding. it drives me crazy

Comment: I would check the values of your ranges. perhaps some formulas are running wild inside of your sheet if it gets activated ?

Comment: I've checked ranges and they are correct. but it was a 'light in a tunnel' for a moment. is there a chance to upload the files just in case if someone would like to examine it?

Comment: Though I don't have any newer info, it might indeed be possible that you encountered an old userform limitation regarding too many *direct* references to controls; this can be fixed by using the controls collection instead - see [Not enough memory crash when loading vba userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140753/not-enough-memory-crash-when-loading-vba-userform?noredirect=1#comment87341599_50140753)

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I don't have that many controls (max 50) and using new excel. but i'll change the code to use controls and let you know

Comment: I've changed most of the controls, but looks like this isn't the case. I'm willing to donate £10 to a charity of some sort (if that's ok with admins) if someone can help me find the error on this. i can upload files to googledrive or something.

Comment: I have uploaded the file to google drive https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12LTuaMoQ-HpI1z8g9F2419dHvHQU4f_4?usp=sharing . if admins don't mind i'll give some money for charity. the process i'm going through is as follows: run 'main.xlsm' > open existing report > select the one from the list >open selected note > select video exhibit from the list > proceed to players > proceed to conversion > save > select another exhbit >proceed to players.  - and this is where the program gets crazy. any help appreciated

Comment: I don't download files as a rule, but it might be worth trying to export the code modules via VB Editor and simply import them back into a new spreadsheet. Further idea: Did you check  API calls/declarations in your code ?

Comment: yeah, I understand. safety first. now the conversation is getting too complicated. I can export userform and modules but that still will be files right? and what are API calls/ declarations? My app uses only files on a drive, there is no internet activity if that was the question

Comment: Apparently not causing your issues. *API* is the abbreviation for Application Programming Interface;  such system near functions need to be predeclared for further use, e.g. like `Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr` 
`

Comment: cheers. I don't use any of those. I'm passing values to other subs, but i guess that's not API

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

So, after spending whole night trying to fix it, I decided to create new Userform and copy all the stuff on it. It works!

I've asked if the problem could be due to file being corrupted and it looks like this was the reason. Userform1 was behaving strangely and I could not understand it.

So unless someone will find different reason for the bug, the official version is - Userform1 was corrupted.