# Excel VBA: Frame doesn't appear in front of ListBox

Tags: excel, vba, controls, userform, z-order

I have a Frame containing other controls, and I have ListBox. All of these are within a Userform. Initially, the Frame is invisible, and there is a button which toggles its visibility. I want the Frame and its contents to appear in front the ListBox, however, this doesn't happen.

I've tried bringing the Frame to the front and sending the ListBox to the back using the Order part of the Format menu, but that hasn't changed anything. I added.

```
'Bring it to the front
DatePickerFrame.ZOrder (0)
    
'Send the ListBox to the back
SearchResultsListBox.ZOrder (1)
```

to my Userform's initialisation, which led to this when toggling the visibility of the Calendar Frame on:

[image: this when toggling the visibility of the Calendar Frame on]

but also led to this when toggling the visibility of the Calendar Frame off:

[image: this when toggling the visibility of the Calendar Frame off]

I also cut and paste this code into the button that toggles the Calendar's visibility, but it led to the same behaviour.

Comment: Does your listbox need to remain visible when you want the Frame to be on top?

Comment: `which led to ... but also led to...` - so which one is it?

Comment: The top image is when the Calendar Frame is toggled on, the bottom image is when the Calendar Frame is toggled off.

Comment: Ideally the ListBox would remain visible when I need the Calendar Frame to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason (I'm yet to figure out why), when you turn something visible while it overlaps something else, the overlap remains..

Start:
[image]

When clicking the button:
[image]

When clicking it again (overlap remains):
[image]

The code I used to play around with that finally worked to show only the listbox when putting the frame back to invisible:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Frame1.Visible = Not Frame1.Visible
    ListBox1.Visible = False 'this is absolutely necessary
    ListBox1.Visible = True
    Frame1.ZOrder (IIf(Frame1.Visible, 0, 1)) 'needs to come after making the listbox (in)visible.
    'ListBox1.ZOrder (IIf(Frame1.Visible, 1, 0)) 'not necessary since you want the frame to be in front
End Sub
```

If that's not the issue, let me know and I'll check some more :)

Answer (score 2):

The VBA controls [are mostly lightweight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2689981/11683). They are not really windows, they are simply drawn on the form.

This visual artifact is a side effect of the MSForms library failing to repaint the surface of other lightweight controls after you hide a control. (They probably didn't think someone would want an overlap, and the form does clear its own background.)

Add `Me.Repaint`:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    DatePickerFrame.ZOrder 0
    DatePickerFrame.Visible = Not DatePickerFrame.Visible
    Me.Repaint
End Sub
```

Comment: Not only delivering a solution, but doubly helpful in trying to explain what is causing the issue's real reason  +:) @GSerg